# Use IdentityApiEndpoints and Razor pages DefaultIdentity UI together

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How can I have both [identity endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization) and [Razor pages identity UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity#configure-identity-services) in the same project?

I tried this code in `Program.cs` but app crash with an error.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyCustomDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyCustomUser>(options =>
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<MyCustomRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyCustomDbContext>();

// app runs successfully without below line
services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<MyCustomUser>();
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists:
> Identity.Application    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String
> name, Action`1 configureBuilder)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String
> name, TOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager`1.get_Value()

Probably something happens twice but don't know how to prevent it!

Answer (score 0):

Likely, instead of `AddIdentityApiEndpoints`, I should have used `AddApiEndpoints`.

Whole code:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<RegUser>(options =>
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<RegRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RegDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
```